# Expand Wpf Treeview to support Sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, treeview

Hi I created this small example, and I would like to expand it to support Sorting.

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

My xaml:

```
<TreeView Name="CountryTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And the code-behind:

```
readonly ObservableCollection<Country> Countries;

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   Countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>
   {
       new Country{Name = "Denmark", SortOrder = 0},
       new Country{Name = "Norway", SortOrder = 1},
       new Country{Name = "Sweden", SortOrder = 2},
       new Country{Name = "Iceland", SortOrder = 3},
       new Country{Name = "Greenland", SortOrder = 4},
   };

   CountryTreeView.DataContext = Countries;
}
```

I would like to make it possible for the `Treeview` to Sort the `Countries` depending on the `SortOrder` value.

It needs to be able to do this on the fly. 
So if I for example change `SortOrder` = 10 for Name = "Denmark" the `TreeView` would automatically reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a default sort for TreeViews. You can either sort the items prior to entering them into the collection, or overwrite the ObservableCollection to include a Sort method.

I overwrite it in one of my projects:

```
public class SortableObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    // Constructors
    public SortableObservableCollection() : base(){}
    public SortableObservableCollection(List<T> l) : base(l){}
    public SortableObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> l) :base (l) {}

    #region Sorting

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in ascending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in descending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    public void SortDescending<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderByDescending(keySelector));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in ascending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">An <see cref="IComparer{T}"/> to compare keys.</param>
    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the items of the collection so that their orders are the same as those of the items provided.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortedItems">An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> to provide item orders.</param>
    private void InternalSort(IEnumerable<T> sortedItems)
    {
        var sortedItemsList = sortedItems.ToList();

        foreach (var item in sortedItemsList)
        {
            Move(IndexOf(item), sortedItemsList.IndexOf(item));
        }
    }

    #endregion // Sorting
}
```

You would then sort it by calling something like

```
Countries.Sort(country => country.SortOrder);
```

I like overwriting it because it let me add additional functionality to it as well such as `IndexOf` or `AddRange`/`RemoveRange`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` with `ListCollectionView` to do the sorting for you, tho you do have to set it for all the child collections as well. I use a linq query to flatten my list to find all the children and set the sorting.

```
foreach (var structure in Model.Structures.Flatten(t => t.SubItems))
{
    var view = CollectionViewSource
        .GetDefaultView(structure.SubItems) as ListCollectionView;

    if (view != null)
    {
        view.CustomSort = (x,y) => string.Compare( x, y );
    }
}
```

elsewhere

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> subitems)
{
    foreach (T child in list)
    {
        yield return child;

        foreach (T other in Flatten(subitems(child), subitems))
        {
            yield return other;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I developed a View Model library which does a number of things, including letting you display hierarchical data in sorted order.  The library is described in [this article](http://www.qnomad.com/wpf/uimodel/).  The piece doesn't include a sorting example, but you can easily modify the Demo 2's View Model to sort its hierarchical data.  Just do the following:

1. The first of three boolean arguments passed to `SampleTreeNodePM`'s base constructor indicates if the View Model collections should use the same indices as the Domain Model collections or not.  Change this value to `false`.
2. The last argument to the `DesiredPosition` method override's return value is a boolean that indicates whether to sort the View Model collection or not.  Change this value to `true`.
3. Following from the previous step, you now need to modify the Domain Model object, `SampleTreeNode`, to implement `IComparable<SampleTreeNode>`.  The `CompareTo` method need simply delegate the job to the `Name` string property:

   ```
   public int CompareTo( SampleTreeNode other )
   {
       return Name.CompareTo( other.Name );
   }
   ```

Regarding updating the position "on the fly" as your question says, just call my library's `HierarchicalPresentationModel.UpdatePosition` method after making the change.