# Using ObservableCollection across UI and Non-UI threads

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I am using the SortableObservableCollection described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487927/expand-wpf-treeview-to-support-sorting). Now I'd like to manipulate it from a UI or a non-UI thread so I tried the solution described [here](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-part-7-accessing-collections-on-non-ui-threads/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class SortableObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private object _itemsLock = new object();

    public SortableObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _itemsLock);
    }

    public SortableObservableCollection(List<T> l) : base(l)
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _itemsLock);
    }

    public SortableObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> l) : base(l)
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _itemsLock);
    }
    #region Sorting

    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector));
    }

    public void SortDescending<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderByDescending(keySelector));
    }

    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer));
    }

    private void InternalSort(IEnumerable<T> sortedItems)
    {
        var sortedItemsList = sortedItems.ToList();

        foreach (var item in sortedItemsList)
        {
            Move(IndexOf(item), sortedItemsList.IndexOf(item));
        }
    }
    #endregion // Sorting

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }

    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
    }

    public new bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return base.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

But this solution in .Net 4.5.2, WPF Desktop Application, throws an exception in the Remove, Add, and Clear method: **System.NotSupportedException**: 'This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.'

So, I went back to using the Application.Current.Dispatcher approach (see below) since the **BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _itemsLock);** mechanism does not work as advertised in the blog post linked above.

My question is: Am I doing something wrong in the first listing or is the blog post incorrect with the claim that thread boundaries can always succesfully be crossed with this mechanism? Is the listing below the best one can do or is there a better solution for managing an observablecollection with bindings across threads?

```
public class SortableObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public SortableObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public SortableObservableCollection(List<T> l) : base(l)
    {
    }

    public SortableObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> l) : base(l)
    {
    }
    #region Sorting

    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector));
    }

    public void SortDescending<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderByDescending(keySelector));
    }

    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer));
    }

    private void InternalSort(IEnumerable<T> sortedItems)
    {
        var sortedItemsList = sortedItems.ToList();

        foreach (var item in sortedItemsList)
        {
            Move(IndexOf(item), sortedItemsList.IndexOf(item));
        }
    }
    #endregion // Sorting

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
    }

    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
    public new void Clear()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            base.Clear();
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
    }

    public new bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            return base.Remove(item);
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move method does not seem to be thread safe

Comment: So, what does that mean? Can I make it thread safe of is the 2nd solution with the Dispaytcher, therefore, the better approach?

Comment: I can't decide which one is better, nor this is the place for opinion. When working on multithread apps you should always take extra measures in order to avoid this exception. You should have a clear image of what's going on on each thread and place `invoke` where necessary.

Comment: and i think `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` should be used just once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Am I doing something wrong in the first listing or is the blog post incorrect with the claim that thread boundaries can always succesfully be crossed with this mechanism?

The thing is that you need to call the `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` method on the UI thread, i.e. you need to instantiate your `SortableObservableCollection<T>` on the UI thread for this approach to work.

If you can't guarantee that the collection will be initialized on the UI thread you should use the dispatcher to marshal all operations that modifies the data-bound collection back to the UI thread. Calling `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` on a background thread won't solve your issue.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I checked my code and there are indeed non-UI threads that create instances of the above collection. Using the dispatcher to call the BindingOperations method makes this work when I wrapp every call to BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _itemsLock); into the Current.Dispatcher,Invoke(...) call. Thanks a lot, I was not aware of this limitation and most sites do not mention it anywhere ...