# What happens if you call BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization from a thread other than the UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

The [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=net-5.0) states the following regarding the `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` method:

> To use a collection on multiple threads, one of which is the UI thread
> that owns the ItemsControl, an application has the following
> responsibilities:
>
> Choose a synchronization mechanism.
>
> Synchronize all access from the application to the collection using
> that mechanism.
>
> Call EnableCollectionSynchronization to inform WPF of the mechanism.
>
> **The call must occur on the UI thread.**
>
> The call must occur before using the collection on a different thread
> or before attaching the collection to the ItemsControl, whichever is
> later.
>
> Call the EnableCollectionSynchronization(IEnumerable, Object) overload
> if using a simple lock mechanism; call the
> EnableCollectionSynchronization(IEnumerable, Object,
> CollectionSynchronizationCallback) overload if using a more elaborate
> mechanism.

Specifically it says "The call must occur on the UI thread."

My question is what happens if you do not call it from the UI thread?
What are the possible side effects?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: You're getting [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348527/using-observablecollection-across-ui-and-non-ui-threads).

Comment: I have tried it and nothing obvious happens. My binding seems to work correctly.